# Android: If function runs with no user unique ID and user isn't authenticated into Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to check for errors in my log in screen which is connected to Firebase, the `OnCompleteListener` that i use checks if:

1) The user has already signed up or not

2) If the user has given me information in my database

Whenever a user inputs an Email that isn't authenticated it will tell him to give information as well(Checking if a unique id exists for a null), it shouldn't happen though or in other words, Why does the `if(task.isComplete() && !task.isSuccessful())`
Run when there is no Unique ID and no User

Here's the `OnCompleteListener` Code, Ignore the `OnSuccesslistener` one

```
Task<AuthResult> authResultTask = firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(Email, Password)
    // if login is complete
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            // dismisses progressbar and checks if the users has already given Essential Information, 
            // If not it will take him to the essential information activity
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            if(task.isComplete() && !task.isSuccessful()){
                // Checks if user has submitted information in the Essential Information activity
                // Takes the Unique ID(if it is present if not it will tell him to sign up or invalid email) 
                // asks the firebase database if he has given information to the database
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                String UserUID = user.getUid();
                reference.child("Users").child(UserUID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        // User exists
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            //Displays Toast telling user that their information is saved in the database
                            Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this, "You have data in our database ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        //User doesn't have information in the database
                        else {
                            // Displays Toast telling user he/she needs to sign in into the firebase database
                            // User goes to UserInformationActivity to give his/her information
                            Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this, "You need to give Essential Information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            // 3 second delay
                            final Handler handler = new Handler();
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // Goes to UserInformationActivity
                                    Intent GoToUserInformation = new Intent(LogInActivity.this, UserInformationActivity.class);
                                    LogInActivity.this.startActivity(GoToUserInformation);
                                }
                            }, 3000);
                        }
                    }

                    // if the checking got cancelled, likability of that happening is small
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }

                });
            }

            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                try {
                    throw task.getException();
                } catch(FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this, "Invalid email, You need to sign up first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // 3 second delay
                    final Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // Goes to UserInformationActivity
                            Intent Signup = new Intent(LogInActivity.this, SignupActivity.class);
                            LogInActivity.this.startActivity(Signup);
                        }
                    }, 3000);
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
                }
            }

        }

    })
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
            Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this, "SuccesListener working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: This looks really weird compared to [the official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth#sign_in_a_user_with_an_email_address_and_password). Where did you get this code?

Comment: Your `task.iscomplete()` is redundant in your first if statement. Look at the method you're in, `public void onComplete(...)`. You only need the `task.isSuccessful()`

Comment: @AndréKool Many sources mainly i composed it myself, it uses datasnapshots to check the child called "users" in the database, and if no data is present then it will take him to an activity to give information, there are comments but if you got any questions feel free to ask :)

Comment: @Michael Yes, but if i put `task.isSuccessful()` the `OnSuccessListener` will work, I don't want the user to see "Successlistener working unless the log in is 100% correct meaning he has given information to database and he has already signed up

Comment: Maybe you have currently signed up user, whose data is still logged in ? You should always check current user according to docs.

Comment: @Ashish The user is supposed to automatically log out when i rerun the application because i don't save the current user from the Signup activity and send it to the log in one, it shouldn't save the logged in user

Comment: What happens when you remove the ! from the first if-statement?

Comment: What's the reason behind having !task.isSuccessful() twice? You should have task.isSuccessful() in the first statement I guess. Thanks to Andre.

Comment: @AndréKool Same Issue persists, When i  removed `task.isComplete()` and removed the ! from `task.isSuccessful()`
I found it to be working a bit more properly, but, I want it to **ONLY** run if the user is Signed up BUT he hasn't given any information to the database, currently when i sign up with an email which isn't authenticated with firebase, it tells me to Sign up (which is what i want) and it tells me also that I need to give Information(shouldn't happen)

Comment: Little Update: removing ! from `task.isSuccessful()` seems to run the if statement even if  i have given information to the database(shouldn't happen) But it works when someone has an account an hasn't given information to the database already